# Number plate recognition, python

Tags: python

The task is for the user to type a *number plate registration* and the code has to recognise if its a standard number plate eg `FP78 TYR` or if its a non standard number plate eg `EEE7 T2` could someone make some code to help recognize which format the number plates are?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a code-writing service

Comment: Not only is this a hugely off-topic question for SO, this is clearly cheating on your GCSE coursework.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if this is what you were looking for:

```
lplate=input("Enter license plate number:")
comp=lplate.split()
if (len(comp[1])==2):
   print("Non standard number plate.")
elif (len(comp[1])==3):
   print("Standard number plate.")
else:
   print("Number plate not recognized.")
```

Comment: Well this is a right solution. Please dont answer a poorly framed question, this will only encourage poor quality questions on SO

Comment: @user4417613 sorry , did not know. New to SO , will keep in mind next time

Comment: @greeninga upvote and mark as answer. It would be helpful :)